# Multi-column ComboBox

Tags: asp.net

Can somebody please recommend a good multi-column combobox control for use in a Web Form?  I'm quite disappointed to not find any multi-column support on the  DevExpress ASPxComboBox control, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the telerik [RadComboBox control](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/combobox.aspx). You can see an online demo of the multi-column functionality [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multicolumncombo/defaultcs.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, the telerik control suite costs just under three times what I'm making on this project.

Comment: Well in that case it's probably not an option. Unless you plan to do more ASP.NET projects in the future.

Comment: I have found a sponsor.  Damn, the telerik stuff looks good since I last used it, maybe Q1 2008, or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I've found better luck exploring javascript controls than asp.net controls; especially if 'free' is a requirement.  I haven't evaluated this control but it's one built with jQuery: http://code.google.com/p/jquerymulticolumnselectbox/

Comment: I'm slowly moving over to the extJS JavaScript framework, but it's too early for me to do an urgent project in.

Answer (score 0):

We used a control from [this](http://aspalliance.com/541_Multiple_Column_DropDown_Box_for_ASPNET) article.  No longer use it, but it was part of an aspalliance article and came with source code (VB.NET).